# android resizing images for all screens (ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi) and put in folders

Tags: android

I am pretty new with android studio. I am wondering how you do all the converting thing ? You resize each image with gimp and creat all the folders. Or is there a program or function in android studio to do resizing for you ? And folders ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your drawable folder

**New > Image Asset** for Launcher Icons, Action Bar and Tab Icons and Notification Icons
**New > Vector Asset** for Material icons, SVD's and PSD's

There is also a tool called [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) which can do even more things for you

Comment: Yh problem with android studio asset was that I dont have SVD or PSD images. For other I couldn't get my png image working as I want. WIll check out Android Asset Studio. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin), I found it the best, all you have to do is import the image you want, and the plugin will create resized images for you.

Answer (score 2):

Those who want to use it online can go https://www.appicon.co/#image-sets. It also work for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AndroidAssetStudio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) utility to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You organize your image/drawable resources in different folders within drawable folder, those are hdpi,xhdpi,ldpi folders. And have images resources in all these folders with respective resolutions with same name.

You could also user vector drawables that are resized according to screen size.

[Go to this page to study this in detail](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)